# Unable to Determine if Root Directory Exists

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the (probably pretty common) use case that I want to create a folder on a shared drive:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Path path = new File("H:\\test-folder").toPath();
    Files.createDirectories(path);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: H:\test-folder: Unable to determine if root directory exists
  at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Unknown Source)
  at org.acme.project.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

(The weird part here is that this exception is practically unknown by Google.)

The problem seems to be entirely Eclipse's fault, since the above code runs perfectly from the command line. But since I need it inside an Eclipse plug-in this information is entirely irrelevant to me. I just need it to work.

So what do I need to do to create folders on network drives?

Comment: Did you really mean two forward slashes there? Backslashes need to be doubled (since backslash escapes get parsed at compile time) but forward slashes shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you check what `path.getParent()` returns? (that is what  `createDirectories()` calls, and if it returns `null` than that exception is thrown). And, while the output in the exception suggests that the double forward slash is properly translated to `H:\test-folder` you should indeed change it to `H:\\test-folder` or `H:/test-folder` as @DanielPryden suggested. Just to be sure.

Comment: @DanielPryden @AndreasFester The slashes were indeed only a spelling mistake while trying to create a simple example. `path.getParent()` correctly returns _"H:\"_.

Comment: what if you try with `File test = new File("H:\\test-folder"); 
    test.mkdirs();` ? Just tested on my network drives and both methods work fine.

Comment: And, did you **really** verify that the h:\ drive is connected **and** that you have write access to h:\ in the environment where you launch the java application?

Comment: @Enigo ` test.mkdirs()` doesn't throw an exception, but returns false (and does not create a directory)

Comment: @AndreasFester at least I can create folders via the file browser just fine

Comment: Try it on the command line (`mkdir H:\test-folder`). Then also launch the java application from the same command line (`java org.acme.project.Main`, provided that you are in the directory above `org/acme/project/Main.class`)

Comment: @AndreasFester wow, both worked. Does that mean the problem has something to do with my IDE (Eclipse in this case)?

Comment: It depends on how you launch eclipse. When you launch it from the desktop icon, it seems that the network drive is not available in that environment. This might be related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331024

Comment: @AndreasFester It doesn't work when I start Eclipse from somewhere else, either. Even if I start it as an Administrator (which is mandatory for Neon anyways).